# Bash flush standard input before a read

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Is there an easy way in bash to flush out the standard input?

I have a script that is commonly run, and at one point in the script [read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) is used to get input from the user.  The problem is that most users run this script by copying and pasting the command line from web-based documentation.  They frequently include some trailing whitespace, or worse, some of the text following the sample command.  I want to adjust the script to simply get rid of the extra junk before displaying the prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [thread on nonblocking I/O in bash](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/84624-nonblocking-i-o-bash-scripts.html) might help.

It suggests using `stty` and `dd`.

Or you could use the `bash` `read` builtin with the `-t 0` option.

```
# do your stuff

# discard rest of input before exiting
while read -t 0 notused; do
   read input
   echo "ignoring $input"
done
```

If you only want to do it if the user is at a terminal, try this:

```
# if we are at a terminal, discard rest of input before exiting
if test -t 0; then
    while read -t 0 notused; do
       read input
       echo "ignoring $input"
    done
fi
```

Comment: I ended up going with a command like this. `while read -e -t 1; do : ; done`.  This seemed to be adequate for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one-liner I settled on similar to ones here:

```
while read -t 1 discard; do echo "ignoring input..."; done # Flush input
```